# Regex for matching different URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex for a URL match and it's not working.

The subject URL is...

```
var subject = "http://encore.lsbu.ac.uk/iii/encore/search/C%257CSab%257COrightresult%257CU1?lang=eng&suite=pearl";
```

The regex is...

```
var regex = /http:\/\/encore.lsbu.ac.uk\/iii\/encore\/search\/C%257CS[a-z][A-Z][0-9]%257COrightresult%257CU1?lang=eng&suite=pearl/i;
```

And I am using JavaScript to test it.

```
var answer = regex.test(subject);
// answer is false
```

The goal is to match any URL with the regex which has keyword changed in the middle of the string but whole string matches the URL. In other words, both string should be matched except the part of keyword shouldn't be checked. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` is a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter followed by a number. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is a combination of them, but only one character. `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]*` is zero or more of these chars. etcetc.. time to read the man..

Comment: the goal is whole string should be matched except part of it should be escaped (don't match) because it's keyword and it's variable.

Comment: what do you mean by escaped??

Comment: change this part:`...C%257CS[^%]+%...`

Comment: in the regex [a-z][A-Z][0-9] this part should not be matched but whole string should be matched. [a-z][A-Z][0-9] this is variable and can be any character, number or anything to one can type from his keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fixed regex:

`/http:\/\/encore\.lsbu\.ac\.uk\/iii\/encore\/search\/C%257CS[a-z0-9]*%257COrightresult%257CU1\?lang=eng&suite=pearl/i`

I made the following changes to it:

- Escaped the dots in the URL with a backslash.
- Changed `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` to `[a-z0-9]*` to match any of those characters repeated zero or more times.

  - You can also use `+` instead of `*` to match the characters once or more, or `{2}` to match them exactly twice (this is the case in your example string, but may not be in all cases).
- Escaped the question mark in the URL with a backslash.

**Edit:** Removed the `A-Z` since it isn't needed (the regex is case insensitive).

Comment: The `/i` at the end makes the whole string case-insensitive, so you really don't need the `A-Z` part if you also have `a-z`.  +1 anyway ;-)

Comment: What instead of only these type of characters, every type of characters are allowed? Including special characters too.

Comment: If you want to match any character you can use `.` instead of `[a-z0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to match the URL except you want to accept any keyword chars instead of the 'ab' in your original string.

For reference, [a-z][A-Z][0-9] says that you want a lowercase character, then an uppercase character, then a digit.  Try using \w instead, which matches any of those.

If you want to accept any length of keyword, then use \s+.  If you want to limit it to exactly two characters, try \w{2,2}.

So the relavant part of your url would be:

```
/C%257CS\s+%257
```

Comment: @Stephen, I think you mean `\w` which matches letters, digits, and `_`.  `\s` means any whitespace character (space, tab, cr, lf).